# Jinja2 is evaluated some Jinja2 code within a <code> block

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I am creating a tutorial on how to use the templating engine jinja2 for a friend of mine. I am using flask to create this tutorial. Ironically, I cannot get the render to work because whenever I write example jinja code in a `<code>` tag, it seems to evaluate it anyway. Once I remove the `<code>` blocks everything renders fine.

```
<pre><code>

{% extends &quot;layout.html&quot; %}
{% block content %}
<h2> test </h2>
{% endblock %}

</code></pre>
```

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: You can use a [`{% raw %}` block](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping).

Comment: That was it. Thanks!!